# How to include frame numbers in beamer class table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Is there a way to include frame numbers in a beamer class table of contents?

In a beamer document

```latex
\documentclass[9pt,handout]{beamer}
```

the `\tableofcontents` command

```latex
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

produces a nice table of contents of the sections and subsections, but without displaying the frame numbers. Is there a way to get the frame number of each entry displayed?